# match two arrays or objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have two javascript objects

```
var category = new Object();
```

I add some attributes to the object as

```
category.Hot = "Red";
category.Cold = "Blue";
category.Warm = "Yellow";
```

I have another object which holds the id, category value and some other attributes

```
var categorization = [];

categorization = {"id1 : Hot","id2 : Cold","id3 : Hot","id4 : Warm"},
```

Now I need to map all the items in categorization with their appropriate color in category. I need something like this.

```
var combinedResult = null;

combinedResult.id1 = {'Hot : Red'}
combinedResult.id2 = {'Cold : Blue'}
combinedResult.id3 = {'Hot : Red'}
combinedResult.id4 = {'Warm : Yellow'}
```

I'm new to javascript so there may be syntactical errors. I have achieved the same in C# any go ahead tips would be appreciated.

Comment: try to use javascript associative array

Comment: There's something odd about `categorization = []` and `categorization = {/* ... */}`. The first is an array, the latter an object. Do you really want to use an object (as you did) or an array (like `categorization = ["Hot","Cold","Hot","Warm"]`? Also, should the result be an object (`combinedResult = {}`) or an array?

Comment: Are you asking for how to structure your data or how to achieve some particular structure? Also, your object notation is wrong: you need to provide a key and a value: combinedResult.id1 = {'Hot' : 'Red'}

Comment: Compare `combinedResult.id1 = {'Hot : Red'}` and `combinedResult.id1 = {'Hot' : 'Red'}` - the latter is correct for an object literal.  Are you looking instead for an array?

Comment: @Rinku, javascript doesn't do associative arrays.

Comment: What exactly are you attempting to achieve (i.e. what is this code meant to do)?

Comment: I want to compare both the objects based on category(which works as a dictionary for me) eg-"Hot. If the categorization has value "Hot" then combinedResult would have appropriate id(from categorization object) and associated category and color {'Hot: Red'}

Eg- combinedResult.id1 = {'Hot : Red'}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may do it this way:

```
$.each(categorization,function(id, val){
    var tempObj = {};
    tempObj[val] = category[val];

    combinedResult[id] = tempObj;
});
```

Here's sample [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZWQAZ/).

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't something along the lines of the below be easier for you?

```
var categorization = [];

categorization.push({"Id" : "Hot","colour":"Red"});
categorization.push({"Id" : "Cold","colour":"Blue"});
categorization.push({"Id" : "Warm","colour":"Yellow"});
```

Then

```
categorization[0].Id, categorization[0].colour etc...
```